# Monitoring data usage android devices

Tags: android

I'd like to write an app which would give the **total amount of data downloaded** over a **period of time**.

Should I have a *service running* in the *background* which keeps track of the data usage or just an *app calling the appropriate api's* when opened would do?

Which all api's could I use for this?

Comment: Please show us _what you have tried so far_! You may have a look at [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) to find out how to ask and what info you should provide

Comment: I now have a working code which has a service which at regular intervals uses the getmobiletxbytes() function call to get the data and subtracts it with the previous value stored in the database and then adds it with the total usage details.. this way i regularly keep updating the database containing the total usage details... However the problem is that by constantly running a service which at regular intervals polls to get some data, the battery life maybe compromised.. So, I was wondering if i could maybe capture some connectivity r some data transfer events to get the same..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [`NetworkStats`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) which is available since API 8.